# Can everyone give us (their/your) takes on this?

Tags: pronouns

I wanted to talk to a bunch of people, asking them to share their opinions. I wanted to say:

> Can everyone give us (their/your) takes on this?

So, I'm not sure whether I should use "their" or "your".

Supposing that this sentence is true:

> Everyone, please give us your takes.

"their" seems to be the wrong one to use.

Does it differ if we're talking to everyone and talking about everyone?

E.g.:

> I asked everyone to give us their opinions.

&

> Hey everyone, give us your takes!

So, in my first sentence, what should I use?

Comment: Note the different person between "Tom, please give me **your** phone" and "Can Tom give me **his/their** phone?". The comparison you are striking doesn't work because these sentences are written in a different person. One is talking to Tom, one isn't. The same applies to "everyone".

Comment: @Flater Got it! Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would ask everyone, as group, for their individual take by saying,

> *Can everyone give me their take on this.*

That is a very common way to request *takes*.  Each person will be expected to have **a take**.   You are asking each person for their individual take.

If you say, *...give me their takes...* it sounds like you expect individuals to have more than one take each.

As to using *your* or *their take* when addressing a crowd, you will be fine using either.  I might be more likely to say *their* with the purpose of it sounding more formal than *your* but  I think it really depends on the speaker's relationship to the crowd. The difference is unlikely to be noticed by the crowd.

Comment: @JOUA Some idiomatic formations just don't switch very well between plural and singular. "Give me your take" is totally idiomatic, but for some reason you just don't talk about "takes" to a group. Maybe if focusing on a collection of individual "takes" ("Mary and I talked to Bob and we both gave him our takes on..."), but not the way the question proposes. Also, note, adding "on this" will help clarify the idiomatic usage.

Comment: @AndyBonner Thanks for letting me know about that. I understand that it would probably sound weird to a person that doesn't know there's been, for example a discussion before the sentence that we want the takes on it. I'll surely use `on sth` to clarify what I mean. Also, if we all know what we're talking about, wouldn't it be okay to not mention the `on sth` part?

Comment: This does not appear to answer the question. The question is whether it's "your" or their", not if it's "take" or "takes".

Comment: You could improve your answer to cover the "Does it differ if we're talking to everyone and talking about everyone?" part as well (although this might have been added after you answered).  And the answer is, I am sure you know, yes.  Talking about a group remains a group "I will ask them to give me their takes on this." vs the talking to a group of individuals you ask each in turn to do something with a "your".

Comment: @Kreiri Hello! Thanks for the comment but I think I implicitly got the answer to my question and an extra point on using singular with everyone that might have gotten mixed up by the answerer. His first and third sentences contain this but you're right, it wasn't a direct answer. If you could add one as an answer, I can change it to the one specifically targeting the question... Thanks.

Comment: @TafT Hi. You're right. I think he should've explicitly pointed that part of the question out but thanks for telling me about it... So, it would be like this: (`Everyone, please give me your answers.` is a direct request to everyone) & (`Can everyone give me their answer(s).` is a general message to everyone, not targeting the group we're talking specifically.) I think both are okay but the second one would mostly be used in an indirect speech, e.g, asking someone to ask everyone to give their answer(s). Am I right on these?

Comment: @JOUA both your examples would sound natural to my ear.

Comment: @TafT Understood! I was thinking of a very specific use case for each (Direct or indirect speech), but in general, thanks for letting me know about it.

Answer (score 1):

Either

> Can everyone give us their take on this?

or

> Everyone , can you give us your take on this?

is okay.

I think

> Can everyone give us your take on this?

sounds odd because it is mixing second and third person. But it is a minor thing and probably would go unnoticed by most people.